# Clicking twice to activate? javascript onclick issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm having an issue with a project I am working on at the moment that is making use of the [Validation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/validate) plugin for jQuery, when the validation error appears I am dynamically applying an anchor tag to it with an onclick. And its this onclick thats the problem...

The first time the validation error appears I have to click the link twice for the onclick event to be fired.

I have had a look at the page through the IE developer tool bar, and the anchor is wrapping the validation message correctly, with the onlick and all the necesary javascript files are attached

What goes on? Any suggestions would be greatfully appreciated :)

EDIT: added code snippets

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#group-edit-form').validate({
            rules: {
                title: {
                    required: true,
                    remote: '<%=Url.Action("ValidateGroupName", new { id = ViewData["GroupId"] }) %>?parentId=' + getParentId()
                }
            },
            messages: {
                title: {
                    required: getMessage (7002),
                    remote: '<%= ((MessagingModel)ViewData["Messages"]).GetMessage (9001) %>'
                }
            }
        })

    });
    function getMessage(messageId) {
        var message = "<a id='errorMessageAnchor_" + messageId + "' onclick='messageBuilder(" + messageId + ")'><%= ((MessagingModel)ViewData["Messages"]).GetMessage (7002) %></a>";

        return message;
    }
```

Comment: can you post a url? there is likely something not quite right with your setup.

Comment: Please post a link or the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the blur event that is interfering with the anchor click.

You can choose one of this options:

- Disable validation on blur event with `onfocusout:false`
- Disable setting the focus on an invalid element with `focusInvalid:false`

Comment: Used the focusInvalid:false option :) worked like a charm, thank you very much!